# Cannot invoke '*' with an argument list of type '($T7, $T14)'

Tags: ios, swift

So, trying to go form obj c to swift and have this problem.

```
    let offset = CGPointMake(location.x - bird.position.x, location.y - bird.position.y);
    let length = sqrtf((Float)(offset.x * offset.x +  offset.y * offset.y))
    let direction = CGPointMake(offset.x / length, offset.y / length)
```

For the third line, I'm getting the error - Cannot invoke '/' with an argument list of type '($T5, $t10)'. What do i need to type cast and to what in order to fix this. Same thing here,

```
func moveSprite(sprite: SKSpriteNode) {

    let amountToMove = CGPointMake(velocity.x * dt, velocity.y * dt)

}
```

The error here is - Cannot invoke '*' with an argument list of type '($T7, $t14)'

Now, dt is an NSTimeinterval and velocity is a CGPoint. When i try to type cast velocity to a double, i just get another error. 
Cannot invoke 'init' with an argument list of type '($T9, $t18)'

What do i need to do here to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot mix numeric types in Swift. You must coerce `length` to a CGFloat.

```
let direction = CGPointMake(offset.x / CGFloat(length), offset.y / CGFloat(length))
```

Also, this line is not Swift:

```
let length = sqrtf((Float)(offset.x * offset.x +  offset.y * offset.y))
```

That's meaningless; that is not how you coerce in Swift.

Comment: And see my new Swift tutorial: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch03.html#_coercion